# SUM Query on sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am newbie, I am very confused how to do sum query. Here is my query :

[image]

and this is an output from my query :

[image]

all i want is Sum my presentase field by month..

i already created sum query, but all i gonna got by my query just error code :((( ..

here my sum query :

```
SUM(IF( YEAR(PO_HARI) = 2016, PRESENTASE_SATUAN, 0)) AS TOTAL_JANUARY
```

and also i added `TOTAL_JANUARY` On my `group_by` but didnt work.

thank you for attention .

Comment: should be IIF and group by should be the reference field

Comment: i dont know how to implement you advices sir Mastafshu.. could you give some example ?

Comment: you got to do some digging... it's not hard

Comment: Google search on sum+group+by+sql https://www.google.com.au/search?q=sum+group+by+sql&oq=sum+group+by+sql&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.10575j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: First decide which product you use: mysql, ms sql server, or oracle. These all have slightly different syntax.

Comment: @maSTAShuFu but its really difficult for newbie Sir :(

Comment: @KeithJohnHutchison thank you for the link

Comment: @shadow my apologize, im using sqlserver

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
select year(po_date) yeardate, month(po_date) monthdate,
        sum(case Point_del
            when 1 then 25
            when 2 then 50
            when 3 then 75
            when 4 then 100
            else 0
            ) TOTAL_JANUARY 
from jbox2_po..POT01A
where month(po_date)=1
group by year(po_date) , month(po_date)
```

you can add 'and year(po_date)=2016' into clause where if you want only 2016 year

Answer (score 0):

IF youre using sql server management studio then try this :::

```
select sum(presentase) from tablename
group by month(PO_HARI)
--here i am assuming that "presentase" is a summable field and 'po_hari' is a date column
```